# Jest - Mocking a function call within the handleSubmit of a form

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write a test that mocks the calling of a function within the `handleSubmit` of a form, however, I am unable to show that the function has been called.

The form is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import signUp from '../../actions/users/sign_up';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Signup extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.showError = this.showError.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;

    this.setState({ [ target.name ]: target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.signUp(this.state);
  }

  showError(type) {
    if (this.state && this.state.error && this.state.error.data.errors[ type ]) {
      return this.state.error.data.errors[ type ][ 0 ];
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    const props = this.props;

    if (prevProps === props) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      ...props,
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12'>
                    <div className='card'>
                        <div className='card-header'>
                            <h4>Sign Up</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className='card-body'>
                            <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } >
                                <div className="form-row">
                                    <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                        <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        className={ `form-control ${ this.showError('email') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }` }
                        id="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        onChange={ this.handleChange }
                      />
                                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                            { this.showError('email') }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-row">
                                    <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                                        <input
                        type="text"
                        name="username"
                        className={ `form-control ${ this.showError('username') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }` }
                        id="username"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        onChange={ this.handleChange }
                      />
                                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                            { this.showError('username') }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-row">
                                    <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                        <input
                          type="password"
                          name="password"
                          className={ `form-control ${ this.showError('password') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }` }
                          id="password"
                          placeholder="Password"
                          onChange={ this.handleChange }
                        />
                                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                            { this.showError('password') }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    email: state.UsersReducer.email,
    username: state.UsersReducer.username,
    password: state.UsersReducer.password,
    error: state.UsersReducer.error,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    signUp: signUp,
  }, dispatch);
}

Signup.propTypes = {
  email: PropTypes.string,
  username: PropTypes.string,
  password: PropTypes.string,
  signUp: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);
```

The `signUp` action looks like this:

```
import { SIGN_UP, SHOW_USER_ERRORS } from '../types';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_ROOT,  setLocalStorageHeader } from './../../api-config';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

export default function signUp (params) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post(`${ API_ROOT }/auth.json`, params).then(res => {
      setLocalStorageHeader(res);
      dispatch(push('/profile'));
      dispatch(signUpAsync(res.data));
    }).catch(error => {
      dispatch({ type: SHOW_USER_ERRORS, payload: { error: error.response } });
    });
  }
}

function signUpAsync (data) {
  return {
    type: SIGN_UP,
    payload: data
  };
}
```

I am trying to simulate the fact that the form will be submitted with the values obtained from the form inputs, which are in the form's state (`email`, `username` and `password`).

The test I currently have is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import Signup from '../../../components/users/signup';
import UsersReducer from '../../../reducers/reducer_users';

describe('<Signup />', () => {
  describe('render()', () => {
    test('submits the form data',  async () => {
      const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

      const initialState = {
        UsersReducer: {
          email: '',
          username: '',
          password: '',
        },
      };

      const store = mockStore(initialState);
      const dispatchMock = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');

      const signUp = jest.fn();

      const wrapper = shallow(<Signup store={store} signUp={signUp} />);
      const component = wrapper.dive();

      component.find('#email').simulate(
        'change', {
          target: {
            name: 'email', value: 'foo@gmail.com'
          }
        }
      );

      component.find('#email').simulate(
        'change', {
          target: {
            name: 'username', value: 'foo'
          }
        }
      );

      component.find('#password').simulate(
        'change', {
          target: {
            name: 'password',
            value: '1234567',
          }
        }
      )

      component.find('form').simulate(
        'submit', {
          preventDefault() {}
        }
      )

      expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalled();

      expect(signUp).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        email: 'foo@gmail.com',
        username: 'foo',
        password: '12345678'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But I keep getting the following error no matter what I try.

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [{"email": "foo@gmail.com", "password": "12345678", "username": "foo"}]
But it was not called.
```

I think it's due to the fact that `signUp` isn't being mocked properly in `shallow(<Signup store={store} signUp={signUp} />)` because when I do `console.log(wrapper.props())` I get:

```
{
...
signUp: [Function],
...
}
```

rather than an indication that it's a mocked function:

```
{ [Function: mockConstructor]
   _isMockFunction: true,
...
}
```

I know that the `signUp` action is being called by the `dispatch` of the test is passing. I can also see the `params` in the `signUp` action when I add a `console.log(params)` into it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try `component.find('form').prop( 'submit')( { preventDefault() {} })`.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle just tried that but that  returns `TypeError: component.find(...).prop(...) is not a function`

Comment: Argh, should be `.prop( 'onSubmit')`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle that goes through but still getting the failed test saying that the mocked function hasn't been called. I'm thinking that the `signUp={signUp}` that's not working - when doing `console.log(wrapper.props())` i can see that signUp is coming up as `signUp: [Function]` (a normal function) rather than `signUp:  { [Function: mockConstructor]...` (a mocked function)

Comment: Ah, its cause you overwrite it in the redux compose `mapDispatchToProps` call. I think you could use  `const actions = store.getActions()` to get the call to `signUp` and test on this.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I think we're getting closer but still not quite there :(. `store.getActions()` is giving an empty array. Should the `signUp` action be added to the `redux-mock-store` in some way?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, maybe it does not work with `bindActionCreators`. Cause in the end it just pass a mock for `dispatch` and collect the calls to it.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle yeah it's weird (and frustrating) - I can confirm that it definitely hits the `dispatch` of the `signUp` action:
i.e. adding `const dispatchMock = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch')`
and doing `expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalled()`.

If I put a `console.log(params) in the `signUp` action, I see the params being called too. Will add the code to my post.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle thanks for your help. I was able to show that the action was being called by importing it with `import * as signUp from '../../../actions/users/sign_up';`  and stubbing it with `const signUpActionMock = jest.spyOn(signUp, 'default');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after ***a lot*** of trial and error, the solution was to mock the action call itself which was done by adding `import * as signUp from '../../../actions/users/sign_up';` and mocking it with `const signUpActionMock = jest.spyOn(signUp, 'default');`

The test now looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import Signup from '../../../components/users/signup';
import UsersReducer from '../../../reducers/reducer_users';

// Turns out this import allowed the signUp action to be mocked
import * as signUp from '../../../actions/users/sign_up';

describe('<Signup />', () => {
  describe('render()', () => {
    test('submits the form data', () => {
      const middlewares = [thunk]

      // Mock the signUp action call
      const signUpActionMock = jest.spyOn(signUp, 'default');

      const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

      const initialState = {
        UsersReducer: {
          email: '',
          username: '',
          password: '',
        },
      };

      const store = mockStore(initialState);

      const wrapper = shallow(<Signup store={store} />);
      const component = wrapper.dive();

      component.find('#email').simulate(
        'change', {
          target: {
            name: 'email', value: 'foo@gmail.com'
          }
        }
      );

      component.find('#email').simulate(
        'change', {
          target: {
            name: 'username', value: 'foo'
          }
        }
      );

      component.find('#password').simulate(
        'change', {
          target: {
            name: 'password',
            value: '12345678',
          }
        }
      );

      component.find('form').simulate(
        'submit', {
          preventDefault() {}
        }
      );

      expect(signUpActionMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        email: 'foo@gmail.com',
        username: 'foo',
        password: '12345678'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your add `signUp` in the `mapDispatchToProps` when adding redux to the view.

As you use `redux-mock-store` you can access all actions that were called by `store.getActions()` So in your case, instead of passing a `signUp` as spy which will be overwritten by `mapDispatchToProps`, it could look like this:

```
const signUpCall = store.getActions()[0]

expect(signUpCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        email: 'foo@gmail.com',
        username: 'foo',
        password: '12345678'
      });
```